# What is "management.py" in Django?

Tags: python, database, django, synchronization

According to this documentation, I have to put something in management.py so that things are created when I run "syncdb"

Where do I do that?  I don't see management.py anywhere.

http://code.google.com/p/django-notification/wiki/IntegratingNotification#Creating_Notice_Types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it in the relevant app's directory. For example, if you have a project like:

```
my_project/
    my_app/
        models.py
        views.py
        tests.py
```

Stick it here:

```
my_project/
    my_app/
        management.py
        models.py
        views.py
        tests.py
```

(That will make a management *module* within the *my_app* package, in Python terminology.)

Comment: Then, when I run syncdb, it will automatically  use that management.py file?  What does " attached to the syncdb signal" mean?

Comment: When Django loads the app, it'll load and execute all modules in that app, so `management` will get executed. Django uses signals to allow parts of an application to get notified about what other parts of the app are doing. `syncdb` is one such signal that gets fired when `manage.py syncdb` is called.

Comment: OK thanks. So basically I just create that file, and that's it. I run syncdb as normal. What if I'm using South? will it run if I'm using  schemamigrations?  If not, then I have to run management.py manually, right?

Comment: Not sure about South, but I imagine it should still get run. It'll get run any time Django has to load the app. (Django loads any app listed in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.)

Answer (score 0):

Not every module in django app is executed upon project start. Only models.py is. It's ugly but you can put the code in there. The `management.py` file is probably a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[From the Django manual:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_syncdb)

> **django.db.models.signals.pre_syncdb**
>
> Sent by the syncdb command before it starts to install an application.
>
> Any handlers that listen to this signal need to be written in a particular place: a management module in one of your INSTALLED_APPS.
>   If handlers are registered anywhere else they may not be loaded by syncdb.

That's because syncdb will not load all the parts of the django project, so if you would define your signals for syncdb in `models.py`, it would not find it, but signals defined in here don't need to be anywhere else in the framework.